# How to embed a font into Windows Store app and to use it from WebView NavigateToString method?

Tags: windows-8, fonts, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to use a font in WebView of my Windows Store App.

I was referring to this page.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/23/about-webview-and-embedded-fonts.aspx

This page use Navigate method of WebView.
But I want to use NavigateToString method.
Pass an HTML string that use the font to NavigateToString method, and want to display that HTML.
Following example 1 was failed.

example 1:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyWebView.NavigateToString("<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><style type=\"text/css\">  @font-face { font-family: \"ipafont\"; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: url(ipaexm.woff);} .ipa { font-family: \"ipafont\"; font-size: xx-large; }</style></head><body><div class=\"ipa\">Hello, Good morning.</div></body></html>");
    }
```

I tried change

src: url(ipaexm.woff);

to

src: url("ms-appx-web:///ipaexm.woff");

but I failed.
Of course, I included ’ipaexm.woff’ font in root folder of my Windows Store app.

Following example 2 was succeeded.

example 2:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       string style = "@font-face { font-family: 'ipa';  src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64," + <BASE 64 ENCODED TEXT OF FONT GOES HERE)> + ") format('woff'), url('ipa__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'); font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; }";

        MyWebView.NavigateToString("<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><style type=\"text/css\">  @font-face { font-family: 'ipafont'; src: url('ipa__-webfont.eot'); } " +  style + " .ipa { font-family: \"ipafont\"; font-size: xx-large; }</style></head><body><div class=\"ipa\">Hello, Good morning.</div></body></html>");

    }
```

I want to use way a kind of example1.
The font I use is about 5MB, so base 64 encoded text of the font is too long.
Is there anything good way to use font by NavigateToString method ?

Comment: [this post from Matt Small](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/23/about-webview-and-embedded-fonts.aspx) on WebView and embedded fonts might provide some help

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I am referring to the page in above question already.

Comment: oops.. sorry about that, I missed that and the nuance of NavigateToString, and it from your post it looks the ms-appx-web:/// option that appears to work for CSS isn't working for woff... I will see if I can find out more.

Answer (score 2):

Just asked this same question myself, and finally found an answer for it.

There are several solutions out there which work if you're using the `Source` property to put HTML in the WebView, but none of these work if you're using `NavigateToString`

Except this.

Put this code into the head of your HTML file. This will not work if in a css file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,<BASE64 STRING OF fontawesome-webfont.woff>) format('woff'), 
        url('ms-appx-web:///fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can use [this page](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/) to convert your woff file. If that link doesn't work there are lots of other pages out there that do the same.